# How to use session variables in front end webpage with jinja2 / Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

hello I have a problem with a select/option html where you can select the page number, so page 1 of 100, 2 of 200 etc... and then goes to page 1, 2, 3 ...
everything works in the following code apart from the fact that inside the select button, after clicking on the page you want to go, after refreshing the page, it goes back to page 1, it always shows: page 1 of 100, even if actually in the url the page number is correct.
I should use a session variable, but the problem is that I'm struggling to understand how to use it with Flask/Jinja2 directly in the html page.
Someone can help?

```
        {%- for page in range (1,(form.total_PAGE.data | int) + 1 ) %}
            {% session['page'] = page %} ?????????
            <option value="{{ page }}">{{ page }}/{{ form.total_PAGE.data }}</option>
        {%- endfor %}
    </select>
```

Comment: just access it like `{{ session['page'] }}`

Comment: where exactly should I put that?

Comment: if I put it like this

Comment: <option value="{{ page }}">{{ session['page'] }}/{{ form.total_PAGE.data }}</option>

Comment: it doesn't show the page number but only the total pages so for ex: /100

Comment: You want set session to hold the value of page right?

Comment: yes, the current selected page is in the variable page, but it wont keep the value inside the select box after you select the page

Comment: try this  `{% set session['page'] =  page %}` then `{{ session['page'] }}`

Comment: I have not tried it and I have not tried setting sessions using jinja

Comment: gives me TemplateSyntaxError: expected token 'end of statement block', got '['

Comment: {% set session['page'] = page %}
      <option value="{{ page }}">{{ session['page'] }}/{{ form.total_PAGE.data }}</option>